# prettier not working. Shows a danger symbol

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Y0d.png)

when Save the file it doesn't format the code.
I did add prettier into the default formatter option.
It worked fine for a day, now its not working at all,
Please help me guys. And let me know what if you have any queries

edit: Not only prettier, every other formatter i tried is not working. Idk why